# Bluetooth won't connect to my Sonundcore Q30

Tags: networking, sound, bluetooth, headphones, bluez

I'm using **Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS** I'm trying to connect a pair of headphones of mine `Soundcore Q30` by Anker. 
Albeit when I try to connect to it the name changes to `BES_BLE` and the connection fails.

My Bluetooth version is 4.2.

I've tried installing `bluez-tools` and connecting through that but the process returns an `Error : Timeout was reached`.

**Please Note**: I understand that this may be duplicate, this is because the original question was never answered.